# Is it possible to modify html codes of a webpage using extensions in Google Chrome?

Tags: html, google-chrome-extension

I'm a complete beginner in HTML coding and Chrome extensions. So, are there any ways to modify a certain part in a webpage's HTML code using Chrome's extension?

For example: Remove a node in a HTML code.

Comment: You can use inspect elements, to change code.. but its temporarily

Comment: Thanks, but i know about that already... That's why i'm trying to use an extension to do it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Content scripts can read details of the web pages the browser visits, and they can make changes to the pages. In the following figure, the content script can read and modify the DOM for the displayed web page. It cannot, however, modify the DOM of its parent extension's background page.

— http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview.html

So yes.

An example of modifying a DOM node is provided in [the Page Redder script](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/samples.html#ede3c47b7757245be42ec33fd5ca63df4b490066):

```
// Called when the user clicks on the browser action.
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
  // No tabs or host permissions needed!
  console.log('Turning ' + tab.url + ' red!');
  chrome.tabs.executeScript({
    code: 'document.body.style.backgroundColor="red"'
  });
});
```

Changing that to call removeChild would be trivial.

Obviously, the changes will be performed on the DOM in the browser with the extension installed and not on the server providing the code to the world.

Comment: Sorry, i don't really understand how to do it... Let's say i want to remove the node called "abc", can you write some codes to show how it's done, please?